# How to set up width by content?

Tags: html, css

I have an icon:

[image]

On hover which appears a tooltip:

[image]

As you can see the problem is that its width is by parent element, is it possible that the width of tooltip would by automatically by it's content?

HTML:

```
<div class="icon">
    <span class="tooltip">Debian: 20%</span>
    <span class="icon-lin-debian" style="opacity:0.2"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.icon{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

span.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #353535;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: -45px;
    z-index: 100;
}

span.tooltip:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #353535 transparent transparent transparent;
    top: 40px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

P.S.
There also is other words, so I can't set width by myself.

Comment: When do you actually display the tooltip?

Comment: Try to remove `left:0; right:0;` and `width:100%`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills on hover image

Comment: But you don't have any `:hover` rule that I can see

Comment: @user1692333 jsfiddle.net. Showing a live example would greatly help others help you on this. Most likely absolute positioning would fix it..

Answer (score 0):

By default, child elements will remain inside their parent elements. This is accomplished by wrapping the content and/or by expanding the parent element.

In this case, the parent element expands to include the child elements because there is no explicit width set on the parent. In order to get child elements to appear to extend beyond the parent element, you would need to set the parent element’s width so it wouldn't expand when the child elements get too wide, and then you'd need to set the child elements’ width to be wider than their parents’. You could then specify `overflow: visible;` on the parent element to allow the children to be fully displayed, even where they extend outside the parent.